# converting a for cycle into a dplyr statement - deviation from mean

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

My aim is to obtain the deviations of a measure from the mean of that measure, per group.

My data look like this:

```
Cluster Media_Name  count
1   1   20minutes   9
2   1   AFP         7
3   1   BFM         5
4   1   BFMTV       6
5   2   AFP         12
6   2   BFM         4
7   2   BFMTV       5
```

In a formula:

```
data <- data.frame(Cluster = c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2"), Media_Name = c("20Minutes", "AFP", "BFM", "BFMTV", "AFP", "BFM", "BFMTV"), count = c(9,7,5,6,12,4,5))
```

So I have got two categorical variables (Cluster and Media_Name) and the count of observations for each pairing.

In order to get a new variable called `deviationFromClusterMean` I work in two steps:

1- I calculate the mean number of occurrences (count) for the variable Cluster

```
clusterMean <- data %>% group_by(Cluster) %>% summarise(clusterMean = mean(count))
```

2- I use a for cycle to obtain for each Media Name (second categorical variable) the deviation from the cluster mean:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {

  cluster <- data$Cluster[i]

  moyenneducluster <- clusterMean$clusterMean[clusterMean$Cluster==cluster]

  data$deviationFromClusterMean[i] <- data$count[i]/moyenneducluster

}
```

It looks pretty ugly to me, and I am sure that I can apply the split-apply-combine strategy here. However the best I can do is not working:

```
data %>% group_by(Media_Name, Cluster) %>% do(mutate(deviationFromClusterMean = count/clusterMean[clusterMean$Cluster == .$Cluster,]$clusterMean))
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to define `clusterMean` separately. The following should work:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Cluster) %>% 
  mutate(deviationFromClusterMean = count/mean(count))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also  use `ave` from `base R`

```
  with(data, count/ave(count, Cluster, FUN=mean))
  #[1] 1.3333333 1.0370370 0.7407407 0.8888889 1.7142857 0.5714286 0.7142857
```